# MS Access - Can't Get Pie Chart Labels in a Report

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, pie-chart

I am building a report in MS Access based on a query that uses custom date range parameters that come from a form input.  I have made a new pie chart using older pie charts as templates, but I just cannot get count labels on my chart for the different values.  The top image is my new pie, and the bottom is a previous pie.

[image]

Where is the control to add labels to my pie?  I can't figure it out!!

This is my query upon which my pie chart is based:

```
SELECT [Projects].[Project Category], Count([Projects].[Project Number]) AS [Number of Projects]
FROM [Projects]
WHERE ((([Projects].Status)="Active") AND (([Projects].Opened) Between [Forms]![Generate Custom Reports]![txtStartDate] And [Forms]![Generate Custom Reports]![txtEndDate]))
GROUP BY [Projects].[Project Category]
HAVING ((Not ([Projects].[Project Category]) Is Null And ([Projects].[Project Category])<>""))
ORDER BY [Projects].[Project Category];
```

Please help!

Comment: i don't undertand your question which labels?  the pie label a re define by your group by or its values

Comment: My question is, I'd like to get the count of projects (shown in the SQL query above) labelled onto my pie chart up top in my Access report.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this turned out to be stupider than I thought.  On the Format part of Chart Settings there is a checkbox, but because my Chart Settings pane was not fully maximized the checkbox was hidden away all the way to the right side and I just didn't see it. I hope this at least is useful to someone who is having trouble finding the labelling setting.[image]